# subclass of tf.keras.Model can not get summay() result

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I want build subclass of `tf.keras.Model` and want to see the model structure with `summary` function. But it not works. The following is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')
        self.d2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        return self.d2(x)

model = MyModel()
model.summary()
```

The error:

> ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first
>   by calling `build()` or calling `fit()` with some data, or specify an
>   `input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build.

Comment: As mentioned in the error, you can mention the input_shape for the conv1 layer. Summary will not be generated till the model is built or compiled. You can try to compile the model first and then call model.summary()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call each layer once to infer shapes and then call `build()` method of the `tf.keras.Model` with model's input shape as argument:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')
        self.d2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
        x = np.random.normal(size=(1, 32, 32, 3))
        x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
        _ = self.call(x)

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        return self.d2(x)

model = MyModel()
model.build((32, 32, 3))
model.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              multiple                  896       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                multiple                  3686528   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              multiple                  1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 3,688,714
Trainable params: 3,688,714
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: why would you add the below lines?

    x = np.random.normal(size=(1, 32, 32, 3)) 
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
     _ = self.call(x)

Comment: @JashShah It is one way to "build" layers and infer shapes, i.e. to let layers now the dependencies between them. There are other ways of doing it. I will update this answer.

Comment: But How do we get real output shapes, instead just multiple in the model summary?

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is listed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25036). You need to provide a model method to infer the model explicitly.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        return self.dense(inputs)

    def model(self):
        x = Input(shape=(1))
        return Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))

MyModel().model().summary()
```

Answer (score 1):

Editing **@Vlad**'s answer to avoid this error `ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_10 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (32, 32, 3)`

**Change this line from**:

```
model.build((32, 32, 3 ))
```

**To:**

```
model.build((None, 32, 32, 3 ))
```

**Final Code:**

```py
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')
        self.d2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
        x = np.random.normal(size=(1, 32, 32, 3))
        x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
        _ = self.call(x)

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        return self.d2(x)

model = MyModel()
model.build((None, 32, 32, 3 ))
model.summary()
```